# Syntax for Multiple Statements in one jQuery

Tags: jquery, syntax

I am new to jQuery and can't seem to get this block of code to work. The first statement executes, but the following two do not. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#print-tab").click(function(){
   $("#print-content").hide().fadeIn();
});

$("#web-tab").click(function(){
   $("#web-content").hide().fadeIn();
});

$("#rest-tab").click(function(){
   $("#rest-content").hide().fadeIn();
});
});
```

Comment: Those are click handlers. They will each only be executed when you actually click on the element they refer to. Have a look at the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle and show us what exactly you meant by "First statement executes but the following two do not"? As far as your code goes, there's nothing running it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your `#print-content` is on top of the others contents and you just never hide it. Could you try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#print-tab").click(function(){
       $("#web-content,#rest-content").fadeOut();
       $("#print-content").hide().fadeIn();
    });

    $("#web-tab").click(function(){
       $("#print-content,#rest-content").fadeOut();
       $("#web-content").hide().fadeIn();
    });

    $("#rest-tab").click(function(){
       $("#web-content,#print-content").fadeOut();
       $("#rest-content").hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```